# How to truncate string using meteor and handlebars?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

In jinja2(python) template engine there is a simple thing for truncating strings:

```
{{ fooText|truncate(200) }}
```

Does meteor(handlebars) provides something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use `|` on [spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) (the engine used on meteor template), but you can do a helper to accomplish this(for example a global [Template.registerHelper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)r).

```
Template.registerHelper('text', function(passedString) {
    var fooText = passedString.substring(0,1); //same as truncate.
    return new Spacebars.SafeString(fooText)
});
```

And use it like `{{ text myString}}`

Here we are using some [Blaze](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) and the [substring method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref%5Fsubstring.asp).

Answer (score 6):

I am using values as options, starting value as well as ending value passed as arguments form template. Try this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('trimString', function(passedString, startstring, endstring) {
   var theString = passedString.substring( startstring, endstring );
   return new Handlebars.SafeString(theString)
});
```

In template:

```
<p>{{{trimString value 0 300}}}</p>
```

it'll print first 300 characters of the value. Hope this help you.