# variable concatenating with String in meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Is there any way to concatenate the string with variable in Meteor template, like other frameworks have i.e in angular `{{'my name is' +name}}` I know it can be accomplished with a helper. But I find the better way or at least, less complicated way to achieve this. I also tried `value="'my name is' {{name}}"` but it always takes the name as string and out put is `"my name is name"`

**EDIT:**
here is my original code line in template

```
<template name="editCategory">
  <!-- Page heading -->

  {{> pageHeading title="my name is {{name}}" category='Catalog' }}


</template>
```

and name value comes from here

```
Template.editCategory.helpers({
    name: function() {
        return this.translation[Object.keys(this.translation)[0]].name;
    }
});
```

i already checked the name value {{name }} in template and working perfect

Comment: Why can't you just use `my name is {{name}}`?

Comment: i already said i need it in title i.e title="{{my string + my varriable}}"

Comment: This is possible in title attributes as well: <tag title="my name is {{name}}"> Maybe the additional quotes you've added are causing the problem?

Comment: Could you add your exact template code?

Comment: @Areca i added original code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Blaze](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Blaze-toHTML). Below is a sample helper,

```
{{> post}}

Template.foo.helpers({post: function () {
  return Template[this.postName];
});
```

The Doc for [template_registerhelper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)

EDIT:

There is also answer submitted earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476505/how-to-truncate-string-using-meteor-and-handlebars)

Comment: you did'nt read my question i mentioned "I know it can be accomplished with a helper."

Comment: @AbdulHameed Using helpers is a good approach as you want to use it in 50 different places.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a helper, so why do not you return the text 'my name is' also from helper?

```
Template.editCategory.helpers({
    name: function() {
        return 'my name is' + this.translation[Object.keys(this.translation)[0]].name;
    }
});
```

In template:

```
{{> pageHeading title="{{name}}" category='Catalog' }}
```

Comment: i just past minimal code i need name in 50 different places in that template with different prefixes and post fixes :)